# Make requests.get() wait untill page is fully loaded?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get source of a webpage using python `requests.get()`, but sometimes it retrieves the page source before some elements even load. Is there a way to make the `requests.get()` wait until certain element appear? The page does not load on javascript and I don't need selenium suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure the page isn't loading any JS? If the page you're requesting is a static HTML page with no JS, then your get request should return it just fine. However, if there are some elements inserted/edited through JS, then your get request won't capture that, which will cause the problems you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "retrieves page before elements load" you are implying that some elements are loaded or retrieved via JavaScript. What you get with `requests.get()` is the initial document and the same thing your browser gets. The difference is that the browser can then read and execute instructions contained in the initial document and fetch more resources, while python can not.

You either have to use `selenium` or go into your browser development tools and see if you can maybe find some endpoints from which the data is getting pulled down.

Comment: I tried to use selenium but the chrome tab crashes after 2 to 3 requests . Any solutions I used everything in stack overflow

Comment: Do you have the url? It is hard for me to say, because i do not know what you are dealing with, but it is possible that you can find the direct API endpoint from which the page is getting the data. You can look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) for a tutorial. Otherwise you have to figure out how to get ```selenium``` to work.

Comment: Not for any specific url while using Chrome driver with selenium in heroku after I make 2 to 3 requests the program generates error saying chrome tab crashed

Comment: Does chrome also crash trying the same actions manually?

Comment: No only while using selenium